# Unable to pass Master-detail id while creating multiple records using ng-repeat

Tags: apex, visualforce, master-detail, repeat, id

I have a use case where I have to display some fields on visualforce page and then whatever data user provides on the page, grab the data and create a record out if it. Now the record needs to be created as a related list to a master object hence I need to supply a master-detail field id named "student_form__c" but when I do that, it gives me an error that the master-detail field cannot be written. Also, I need to provide user a "Add new" button on visualforce page. Upon clicking the button, the same set of fields appear again on visualforce and a record gets created again upon saving it. So this way user can create n number of records.

Visualforce page:

```
<apex:page controller="Dummy_Controller">
  <Apex:form>
     <apex:pageBlock>
         <apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:commandButton action="{!Save}" value="Save" />
            <!-- Has to be immediate - otherwise the form tries to "submit" and triggers built in validation --> 
            <apex:commandButton action="{!AddNew}" value="Add New" immediate="true" />
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>

        <!-- Repeat for each record, create a "row" where we can put inputs --> 
        <apex:repeat var="record" value="{!Records}">
            <!-- wrap each record with an actionRegion - ensures the fields are submitted when adding new rows --> 
            <apex:actionRegion>
                <apex:pageBlockSection>
                        <apex:inputField value="{!Record.Name}"  />
                        <apex:inputField value="{!Record.Status}"  />
                </apex:pageBlockSection>
            </apex:actionRegion>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</Apex:form>
```

Here is my controller:

```
public class Dummy_Controller {

public List<Application__c> Records { get; set; } // our variable 

public Dummy_Controller() {
    Records = new List<Application__c>(); // initial state 
    Records.add(new Application__c()); // initial record 
}

public PageReference Save() {

    /*I have already fetched the studentformid from url in apex class 
      constructor like this Id StudentFormId = 
      ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'); Now I want to 
      assign this fetched id to student_form__c field*/

     for(Application__c record:records) 

     **// Here is the problem**

    { 
       record.student_form__c = StudentFormId; 

     }

    insert Records; // save all records 

    return new PageReference('/' + Records[0].Id); // redirect to saved record 
}

public PageReference AddNew() {
    Records.add(new Application__c()); // add another record 

    return null; 
  }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues I can see, because in the save method you are looping `records` which are type of `Application__c`.

You have created `List<Account>`,it should be `List<Application__c>`

```
public List<Application__c> Records { get; set; } // our variable 

public Dummy_Controller() {
    Records = new List<Application__c>(); // initial state 
    Records.add(new Application__c()); // initial record 
}
```

Same way, in the Add new method

```
public PageReference AddNew() {
    Records.add(new Application__c()); // add another record 

    return null; 
  }
```

In the above solution, I have presumed that a Custom object cannot be a Master of Standard object (Account).

**Update**

When you are creating an instance of record, assign the MasterId at that moment and no need to update  that in `save` method.

```
public PageReference AddNew() {
    //retrieve StudentFormId in the constructor and use it here.
    Records.add(new Application__c(student_form__c = StudentFormId)); // add another record 

    return null; 
  }
```

Otherwise, in the configuration choose `allow reparenting` on the master-detail relationship so that the id will be writeable.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am sorry I had some typos in my above code, mixed two codes. I have updated the code above. I am dealing entirely with Application and Student form object. Studentform is the master of application object and both are custom objects. I am having issue in specifying the master-detail field id in order to create records at the appropriate place.

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: I tried that. It gave me this error on visualforce upon submission. 
Error: Insert failed. First exception on row 0 with id a1Rr0000000eI6hEAE; first error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id] I don't know why, it is not the actual record's id, it is just a master-detail field id.

Comment: refer https://opfocus.com/understanding-cannot-specify-id-on-insert-exception/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I guess the issue was that I was trying to insert a list that was already inserted in the previous run. I resolved it by adding this statement after insert Records; command in Save method. 

Records = new List<Application__c>();

Comment: That is not been specified at your question, atleast your issue got resolved

Comment: There were actually two issues. First one was providing master-detail id. After I solved that by specifying the id right where I am defining the list, it lead to second issue that I mentioned above. Thanks for all the help.